# How to set background colour for PsiJavaToken?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to implement an IntelliJ plugin, one feature is we allow developers select a code snippet, and then set the background color for the region. Therefore, I want to ask whether it is possible to set a background color for PsiJavaToken or for a selected region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. One way to achieve this is to create a local inspection, create problem descriptors in checkFile() method and use ProblemDescriptor.setTextAttributes() to set background color.

Comment: Thank, but can it be persistence? I mean when we re-open the project, the background color disappears?

Comment: The marked snippets data can be stored with project and retrieved by the inspection. In that case highlighting will be restored.